# Return a properly formatted JSON object from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I'm using an external API that gives me a a JSON object as a response. I'm running a few API calls and am trying to add them to an array and then return the whole thing to my Vue app but for some reason, when I console.log it, it's not display how an object should. This is what I'm getting...

[image]

Here's the call that brings back the object.

```php
$response = $divisionApi->addDivision(
        $request->onBoard['division'], 
        $request->onBoard['division']
);
```

But when I do this, the object just seems to convert into a long string.

```php
$responseArr[] = array('division' => $response);
$responseArr[] = array('merchant' => $response);
$responseArr[] = array('division' => $response);

return $responseArr;
```

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Comment: Well normally when you console.log an array of objects in JS you can click on object keys and expand the data but this seems to be restaurants the object as one whole big string that cousins the keys and the values.

Comment: `$response` is most likely a json-string so you need to decode the data before adding them to your array: `json_decode($response)`

Comment: you need to `json_decode` json response from API and then at the time of return you need to do `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

You need php's `json_encode()` function. It takes your array and converts into a json formatted string.

The other way around it's `json_decode`.

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php.

If the issue is on JS side, you might need to parse the JSON string into an object with `JSON.parse()`, documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse